# PDO object not getting constructed properly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am creating a PDO object like this:

```
try {                                      
   $dbh = new PDO( "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name" , $user, $passwd );     
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
   echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   die();
}
```

but there are no errors, no Exceptions and the PDO object doesn't have anything in it:

```
var_dump( $dbh );
```

outputs:

```
object(PDO)#5 (0) {
}
```

Username/password and database name are all correct.

Many thanks.

Comment: Try var_dump($e) and show us what it says.

Comment: It __is__ a PDO object.... what makes you think it hasn't been created correctly? Properties aren't always public

Comment: @MarkBaker: True, but `var_dump()` normally displays private properties as well. PDO is kinds of special in that sense.

Answer (score 5):

This should be a working PDO object. Try using it to confirm.

What made you think it was "constructed incorrectly"?

Answer (score 0):

Try thi for pdo connection

```
    <?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

when your run this you will get
for vardump($dbh) as

= object(PDO)#1 (0) { } =

Reference :[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: Actually a pdo is an instance it won't return anything when success ,, you can't see the build of objects in php.net

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm by using phpinfo() function that PDO installed on server or not. If PDO installed on server than use following method to connect to database:

```
 $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

Host : Localhost or depend on you server.

dbname : database name

$user : database user name

$pass : database password